# Separation of presentation and logic

Tags: c#, presentation

I'm now writing a program, which will allow processing data expressed in the form of graphs. These graphs will determine workflow of the processing and they are actually an essence of this program (in terms of being the main object being edited by the user).

It is very, *very* tempting to put all the processing, data containment and presentation in a single control, which will also display these graphs and handle user interaction. From one side it seems to be violation of the presentation/logic rule, but from the other I'm certain I will write surely at least 2x or 3x less code, because I won't have to take care of constant synchronization between data model and the control, which will present this model (+encapsulation, interfaces, proxy classes etc.)

I'm wondering how it is done in editors like Word. Is the data displayed by the control really physically separated from the presenter or are they combined? If you use the Word document control in your program, you ask the control to perform operations on text, what would suggest, that there is no separation (but we don't know how does it work under the hood).

So the question: is separation between data presentation and logic worth it *even* if it requires like 2x or 3x more code to keep everything consistent and synchronized? (yes, I mean 2x or 3x).

---

I've described the situation in more detail in the next question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373108/how-to-separate-logic-from-presentation

Comment: 2x or 3x more code there, but 2x or 3x less code in your unit tests since you can correctly mock things and test precise behaviours.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault I'm not sure if it is possible. The data are meant to be displayed (they are visual by design), so surely I'll have to keep information about things like their position or size, which are presentation-specific things. Imagine, for example, writing unit tests for the drawing area of Gimp or document area of Word. Do you think it's possible? Or are they being tested more by functional than unit tests?

Comment: Are you using wpf? On reason to abstract it out maybe the need for future implementations such at win forms, wpf, rt... Try not to tie yourself to one technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally prefer loosely coupled layers my code. In your case, I would have few interfaces with my implementation. However, I would also like to provide an opportunity to consumers to play around with certain things.

So, I would start with interfaces that provide data to my graph. Assuming it uses data coming in from a database, I could use a database layer that works with `IDbConnection` and other such interfaces. Now, I can support anything that has a provider that uses these interfaces.

Next is processing. Once data is available we need a generic way to pass it around. So, think of some more interfaces that help you do that. And your Model (class whose instance would represent data) must implement it. This enables adding and removing business rules easily.

Now, the appearance. For controls, I prefer using public events with a default handler embedded in the control itself along with properties. For instance. on click a bar in bar chart, it's color should become say red. Now a consumer likes green, so, give a property  for him to do it. He also wants a tool tip and some more details on mouse hover. So, give him a event to handle.

I understand this is way too generic and hope it is at least somewhat helpful.

Comment: The core problem with your approach is (and maybe I didn't stressed it in my question), that all: the data and way of their interaction is strictly specific to my program (yes, I am *absolutely* sure I won't reuse it anywhere). They data will be created in my program and processed in my program only. This is why I don't actually *need* so many interfaces and layers. What I want to say is, that it seems, that I won't gain much by separating the layers and that's why I'm struggling not to do so.

Comment: Ok, in that case, think of the person who would maintain it. At least logically divide the code into different classes for that poor soul. Please do not dump everything in one class or method.

Comment: Actually, this is my private project, so that poor person will be me :) I absolutely have no aim to keep everything in single method or class, but in this particular case keeping the separation seems to me to require *a lot* more work than leaving it all inside the control and that's why I'm wondering, whether there are exceptions of that separation rule. Also, data items will *have* to store presentation-specific data like position or size, so actually separation seems to be unnatural in this case.

Comment: In every other program I've written I always managed to separate the layers, but I'm attempting to implement this program for the third time and for the third time I'm having thoughts about breaking the separation in this specific case. I'm wondering how it is done in big editor programs like Word, Excel or PowerPoint - is the data really separated from the editor or does the editor contain and manage the data?

Comment: There is no rule that forces you to do things this way. You must decide what is good for your application. If you are sure about what you mentioned, there is no point in taking pain to do so. Yes, purists may disagree but I do not see a point in doing all this.

Comment: Maybe I just have to try and see what happens :)

Comment: MS Office, is heavily interface driven. Check out any article on web about Office interop and you would realise.

Comment: Yeah, but that tells us nothing. These interfaces may as well be implemented by the control or its parts themselves...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49598/discussion-between-danish-and-spook)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be operating under a very strange idea of what "seperation of concerns" means.  If your design would actually call for writing twice as much code, you are doing something very, very wrong.

A multi-layer architecture works for complex line-of-business web applications because the translations between database, business logic, and DOM are so thorny and prone to migration.  For more narrow focus, such as designing a single PHP class to translate an array of numbers and a property blob object into a pretty graph, your separation can and should be tighter and more compact.

You'd probably want some seperation between your control's internal storage of the data and the interface you take from outside, but only because you're going to want some testing and verification on that.  (And as soon as you finish your "never going to need to change this" demo, you'll be asked to make a version for mobile or print or something.)

Answer (score 0):

So the question: is separation between data presentation and logic worth it even if it requires like 2x or 3x more code to keep everything consistent and synchronized? (yes, I mean 2x or 3x).

I would strongly recommend separating out the layers. There are a few reasons:

- Controls often start simple then become more complex over time.
- Controls may be reused in other areas of an application or other applications.
- If controls need to interact with one another, having events isolated will greatly simplify code.

Comment: Yeah, but this is a specific situation, where the control is responsible for all *complex* input from the user. If I separate layers, for *each* new functionality I will have to implement it in the logic layer, interaction for it in the control and mechanism, which will keep data and control consistent. If I implement it inside the control, I have everything in one place. Secondly, the control will be (by requirements) so specialized, that there's virtually no chance of being reused in other applications. Try to think of this control like Word's editor control.

Comment: @Spook Microsoft Word runs on Windows and Mac, which use different APIs for the UI, but the core code (called by the UI) may well be the same.  That's part of what separation of concerns is about.

Answer (score 0):

Separating presentation from logic is a guideline not a rule.

While is most cases MVC is a good idea, there are a few cases where it is not. Think about "paint" or "photoshop" how much sense would it make to separate the presentation from the "logic" when the whole point of the "logic" is to manipulate what is presented.

I have come across this in trading apps. Wo betide anyone who presents a trader data using anything but ye ancient Rueters terminal colors. The best place to set these colors is in the presentation layer using business rules. You can do it in the "business logic" but this means sending a ton of extra information to the presentation layer -- about presentation; either way you are breaking the "rule".